# Osmdroid Cannot resolve symbol for DefaultResourceProxyImpl and ResourceProxy

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid

In the IDE of Android Studio when I insert the import:

`import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;`

I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol ...."
All other imports of org.osmdroid.* are ok, but not for the 2 import above.

My build.gradle implements:

```
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.3-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.3'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:6.1.3'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.1.3'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:6.1.3'
//implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-third-party:6.1.3'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-shape:6.1.3'
```

My question is What to implement more to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance.
Fabio

Answer (score 0):

The resource proxy was removed years ago. It's no longer needed since osmdroid switched to the android archive (AAR) format vs a jar. There is no replacement as the APIs were updated to no longer require it